# Can't solve the error in raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, raspberry-pi, nameerror

i'm new to raspberry pi and wrote a simple led blink program:

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time
    GPIO.setwarnings(False)
    GPIO,setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
    GPIO.setup(3,GPIO.OUT)
    while True:
       GPIO,output(3,1)
       time.sleep(1)
       GPIO.output(3,0)
       time.sleep(1)
```

but when i run it i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ledblink.py", line 6, in <module>
    GPIO,setmode(GPIO.BCM)
NameError: name 'setmode' is not defined
```

Comment: If you put another line break between "led blink program" and the import statements, your code will format better :)

Comment: Is that a typo? 'GPIO.setmode' notice the dot and not a comma as 'GPIO,setmode'

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you've mistakenly used a comma instead of a full stop when trying to call the setmode method

Change

```
GPIO,setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
```

to

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
```

Comment: Additionally `GPIO,setmode(GPIO.BCM)` needs to be changed to `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)`

Comment: Whoops. Never had one. You write the code on the PI do you? You dont develop on a machine and send the code over?

Comment: The Pi has IDLE built in, and personally I would recommend using that.  Obviously it sucks that IDLE has no intelisense, but you take what you can most times.

Answer (score 3):

```
GPIO,setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
```

That comma after GPIO should be a period.  Same thing for this line:

```
GPIO,output(3,1)
```